# New to VSTO development

Tags: c#, vsto

I am working with an application that creates a word document from a Word 2010 template.  There is a dll in the application that allows different data to be added to the document once the document has been created.  However, I don't know how VSTO works exactly so I don't understand when any dll that would run when a VSTO-created Word Document is opened.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try starting here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb871648(v=office.12).aspx.  <strike>VSTO is a bit odd, I only have experience of Excel but when you create a VSTO app you'll need to provide customisations on the ribbon so that when clicked, your code is activated.</strike>

Comment: You don't need to do anything with the ribbon. It's usually a convenient user interface for Office apps, but you can absolutely create a VSTO project with no ribbon at all.